# Add smooth trendline to ggplot without overshooting too much

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to put a smooth trendline to my plot based on non-regular data with some gaps. I tried using geom_smooth (loess), however it makes a weird decline at the point where data is missing. And does not really follow the points in general. How do I avoid this?

(It is the first time I made a reproducible example so please tell me if I should have done it differently)

dataset:

```
`(structure(list(date = structure(c(18807, 18807, 18807, 18807, 
18807, 18807, 18814, 18820, 18834, 18834, 18834, 18835, 18835, 
18835, 18835, 18835, 18835, 18841, 18841, 18841, 18841, 18841, 
18841, 18841, 18841, 18841, 18847, 18847, 18847, 18847, 18847, 
18847, 18848, 18848, 18848, 18849, 18855, 18856, 18856, 18856, 
18856, 18856, 18856, 18856, 18856, 18856, 18862, 18862, 18863, 
18863, 18863, 18863, 18863, 18863, 18890, 18890, 18890, 18890, 
18890, 18890), class = "Date"), sulphate = c(38, 38, 39, 37, 
39, 38, 50, 47, NA, NA, NA, 41.34, 40.61, 39.2, 38.69, 39.1, 
38.83, 46, 47, 46, 48, 47, 48, 47, 47, 47, 50, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51.1, 48.8, 51.9, NA, 67, 64, 64, 65, 64, 69, 64, 68, 68, 
70, NA, 54, 55, 55, 55, 56, 55, 55, 70.5, 70.8, 71.2, 71.6, 71.5, 
71.5)), row.names = c(NA, 60L), class = "data.frame")`
```

code:

```
`library(ggplot2)
WQ <- read.csv('data_WQ.csv', dec='.', sep=';', header=TRUE)
WQ$location <- as.factor(WQ$location)
WQ <- filter(WQ, !location=='4')
WQ$sulphate <- as.numeric(WQ$sulphate)
WQ$date <- as.Date(WQ$date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
lims <- as.Date(strptime(c("2021-06-21", "2021-09-23"), 
format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

WQ %>%
ggplot((aes(x=date))) + 
geom_smooth(aes(y=sulphate, x=date), span=0.7,inherit.aes=FALSE, col='darkgreen')+
geom_point(aes(y=sulphate, x=date), col='orange')+
xlab('date') +
ylab('sulphate mg S/l') +theme_bw()+
theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1), 'cm'), text=element_text(size=11), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_text(size=11),axis.title.y=element_text(size=11))  +
scale_x_date(breaks = '2 week', date_labels='%d/%b', limits=lims)`
```

Comment: You could try adjusting the `span` argument in your `geom_smooth` statement.

Comment: I did figure out that solution, however it is really important to see certain inclines and declines over certain periods, which is not possible anymore with increasing the span. Decreasing the span results in even more unexplainable trends.

Comment: A span of 0.4 gives a very nice result. It shows a line that goes through all the clusters without significantly overshooting anywhere. If you want the most accurate trendline, try `stat_summary(geom = 'line' , aes(y=sulphate, x=date),inherit.aes=FALSE, col='darkgreen')+`

Comment: The result is indeed not too bad with changing the span, however, I have other parameters that have similar issue which are not being resolved using a span of 0.4 (or other). Stat-summary does not give me the desired results. To understand this problem better, could you explain why the trendline 'overshoots' like that? The trendline basically assumes certain peaks, far from the actually measured data, what does it base on then? Is there any other method to add a smooth trendline which might fit my data better? Thanks!